# JSON encode multiplies arrays as single array

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

```
$array = array(
    $this->_order->revenue_seller($value,$from,$to),
    $this->_order->refund_seller($value,$from,$to),
    $this->_order->customers_seller($value,$from,$to),
    $this->_order->sales_seller($value,$from,$to)
);
$this->response($array,200);
```

I want the data to be be displayed as a single array, but as we can see, the output is begin displayed as array of arrays:

```
[
    [
        {
            "min_amount":"2.00",
            "max_amount":"2.00",
            "avg_amount":"2.000000",
            "total_revenue":"2.00"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "total_refund_amount":"1.00"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "created_at":"2013-03-24 15:04:35"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "quantity":"1"
        }
    ]
]
```

How can I make the data appear as one single array?

Like this:

```
[
{
"day":"2013-03-19",
"min_amount":"0.00",
"max_amount":"0.00",
"avg_amount":"0.000000",
"total_revenue":"0.00",
"quantity" : "1",
"total_refunded_amount":null,
"created_at":"2013-03-24 15:04:35"   
}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are getting array return by all four function than use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) as,

```
$array = array_merge($this->_order->revenue_seller($value,$from,$to),
                     $this->_order-refund_seller($value,$from,$to),
                     $this->_order->customers_seller($value,$from,$to),
                     $this-_order->sales_seller($value,$from,$to));
$this->response($array,200);
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.org/8SPXvDUB)**

Comment: sir i want it as a single one as mentioned above now.

Comment: So you should get single by mention answer. Can you post what you getting ?

Comment: [
{
"min_amount":"2.00",
"max_amount":"2.00",
"avg_amount":"2.000000",
"total_revenue":"2.00"
},
{
"total_refund_amount":"1.00"
},
{
"created_at":"2013-03-24 15:04:35"
},
{
"quantity":"1"
}
]   I am getting this one

Comment: Can you paste bin your complete code ? Also post one of the array you getting by calling function above.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3TE0twmM here it is .. i have pasted one of the function like this

Comment: @RishiReddy - So I can see that you're not using the array_merge as I suggested you.

Comment: @RishiReddy after using arrray_merge i am getting the output as mentiioned above .. so i remved it ..

Comment: It is because you must be using array_merge wring way as I show you in demo. So I need to check your code for array_merge.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31629/discussion-between-rikesh-and-rishi-reddy)