# Multiplying two arrays from MYSQL data into a new PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have looked at these examples so far [Multiplying two 2D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840877/multiplying-two-2d-arrays) {this is c++ so not sure how helpful ti will be for php}
[JSON encode multiplies arrays as single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058326/json-encode-multiplies-arrays-as-single-array) {although php code it is not multiplying two arrays}
[Multiplying two arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432326/multiplying-two-arrays-in-php) {this is pretty much what i am trying to do but the solution is not working so not sure if it the solution or it is not wha ti need}

Basically what i am trying to do is, take two arrays that are generated from a mysql database into another array with the total of the multiplication of the results from the two mysql number arrays.

I have tried quite a few different ways as listed below with no luck so far.

```
<?php

    //Database connection
            $db=mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***") or die(mysqli_error($db));

    //This is to test if there is a php scripting error ie white screen etc if no results are displayed
            echo "test";

    //SQL Statements
            $sql4="SELECT * FROM invoicequote";
            $sql5="SELECT SUM(unitprice*units) AS total FROM invoicequote";

    //Query database for results
            $result4=mysqli_query($db,$sql4) or die(mysqli_error($db));
            $result5=mysqli_query($db,$sql5) or die(mysqli_error($db));

    //Arrays of services performed and prices
            $service=array();
            $workdone=array();
            $unitprice=array();
            $units=array();
            $total=array();

    //While loop for invoice or quote information
            while($num = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4))
                    {
                            $service[]=$num['servicesused'];
                            $workdone[]=$num['serviceworkdone'];
                            $unitprice[]=$num['unitprice'];
                            $units[]=$num['units'];
                            //$total[]=($unitprice*$units);
                    }
    //Also tried $total[]=($unitprice[]*$units[]); but this gave a white screen i suspect because there was no index supplied

    //Put total into array by multiplying the unit price and number of units
/*
            for ($unitprice as $price && $unit as $u)
                    {
                            $total=array($price*$u);
                            echo $total[0];
                    } //This gives a white screen it appears to be a infinite loop
*/
    //use mysql to do the calculations before it comes out into php
/*
            while($num = mysqli_fetch_array($result5))
            {
                    $total[]=$num['total'];
                    echo $total[0]; //this gives the total off all prices rather than individuals prices
            }
  */
    //putting results into a array
    $arr=count($units);

    for($i=0;$i<$arr;$i++)
    {
            $total[]=$unitprice[$x]*$unit[$x]; //this gives a white screen as well
    }

    //Display the results
            $arrlength=count($units);

    //This is the prefer way to display the results but i am open to anything that works
            for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
            {
                    echo $total[$x];
            }

    mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Database information removed

I suspect it the way i am trying to get php to do the actual calculation that is the problem as the data for each of those variables displays fine only when i try to multiply them does it become a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do,

```
$total[]=$num['unitprice']*$num['units'];
```

The below line isn't right because `$unitprice` and `$units` are arrays and not values.

```
$total[]=($unitprice*$units);
```

`[]` syntax is used for appending to array so the following would also not work

```
$total[]=($unitprice[]*$units[]);
```

But you could use a for loop instead like below assuming that all the arrays are of same size.

```
$count = sizeof($unitprice);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
  $total[$i] = $unitprice[$i]*$units[$i]; //$units[$i] fetches the value at the ith index lllr is the case for $unitprice also
}
```

Comment: the question has a LOT of code in it. It would be nice if you would help the asker by explaining where this line of code goes, and drawing attention to the differences between this line and what the asker had instead.

Comment: Sorry for late response, when initial tried it, it never worked, but seems the page i was testing the code on has become broke or cached in wrong state, when i added it to live another separate test page it worked great, also seems i had more a less got it on one of my examples but i forgot to replace x with i